# Facebook API user array

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have this code  to get the albums of the user and then each photo in each album.

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            getUserAlbums();
        } 
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } 
        else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    getUserAlbums();
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        }
    });`
```

The problem is, it works great with my fb acount, gets all the photos, but doensn't work with any other fb account I tried. (siblings) I print screened the array `console.log(response)` and realize that it works on mine because I have some extra arrays!

images included:

[image: my array:]  [image: other people's array:]

Why is that? Are the accounts different????

Comment: You are not asking for the necessary permission in your `FB.login` call – so I assume it works for your account, because you have given that permission to your app earlier already, but not for users that go through the login flow you implemented here.

Comment: When they log in the app requests them to "okay" the app, isn't that the green light for permisions?

Comment: You should go read the docs on how the permission system works.

Comment: i changed it to `}, {scope: 'user_tagged_places,user_photos'});` and i still get the same arrays.